# background-image load or display delays even though cached in IE7

Tags: css, performance, internet-explorer, background-image, delay

I have a seperator li which has a background image, in an expanded tree menu, it may appear several times using the css:

```
.simpleTree .line {
    background:url("/images/Css/gridLine.gif") no-repeat 0 0;
```

Even tho it is cached (from previous instances), there is still a slight delay in IE7 (~500 - 1sec) before all the background images fires up. Is there a better way to do this or make it quicker?

Comment: it's more likely that some other factor causes this. url?

Comment: if it's already cached, I doubt url is an issue.

Comment: i meant, you could post the url, and see if i can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell the delay shouldn't be because of a single gif image. Check your site with [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) or [PageSpeed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/). Maybe some other content is blocking your image to appear fast (like javascript execution).

Comment: I'll have a go with YSlow and see how it goes. As far as I can tell at the moment, the page is fully loaded already.

Comment: I've removed some pngs (sprite images) from the page, and that seems to have solve the problem. Maybe the png rendering was taking too long.

Answer (score 0):

There are some things that you can try. You can try to reduce the size of your image and than in the CSS use the TAG "repeat-x" or "repeat-y".

In some cases, .gif's are not the best type to display images, you can try saving your image in diferent formats and see if they get smaller.

Best Regards

Comment: for a line image with 2 pixel colors... in GIF.. it is as small as it can get. I've done away with repeat even to reduce rendering time.